# Import error: No module named "utils" when using pickle.load

Tags: python, import, pickle, importerror

I firstly dump some stuff into a pickle file using pickle.dump. in utils.load_data, my project hierarchy looks like this

```
project1
  -utils
     -__init__.py
     -load_data.py
  -data
  (other folder...)
```

Then it outputs a pickle file into a data folder. Then I move the .pickle file to another project, the project hierarchy is

```
project2
   -data
   -main.py
```

When I run a pickle.load() operation in this main.py, it prompts the error as the title. However, if I move main.py back to project1 folder, then the error disappears. So the issue must be from the file.

My question is, why does pickle try to import the package from where it was born? Could anyone share a good explanation for this? I got quite confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, unpickling will import any class that it finds in the pickle data. This means if you have pickled a custom class and you are unpickling it somewhere, pickle will try import the module (`utils` in this case). So you need to have the `utils` module inside `project2` folder

Follow [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#subclassing-unpicklers) for more information

Comment: You can accept the answer if it was useful. It helps others discover the answer.

Comment: This is the best answer I can find on this topic!

Comment: Many Thanks for your anwser, it helped me a lot, after huge exploration on stackoverflow !